# Simulating a map with DataVsualization.Chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, coordinates, gis

VB2010 I am using the DataVisualization.Charting.Chart control and am using it as a very crude map of several geographic points. I have that working and it looks good but am trying to see about adding an image to the chart so that it would simulate the land masses. The problem I see is that I zoom around the chart programmatically, so not sure how i can anchor the image to certain x,y coordinates. I don't want to go the whole GIS component as those types of controls are just too much for this fairly simple app.

Update: Well I sort of resolved it. I generated a full world map based on the WGS84 (some would call geographic) projection. This splits the world into perfect 20d x 20d squares. I added this graphic to the BackImage property of my main Chart. I add my points but force the extents of the graph to x: -180 to 180 and y: -90 to 90. Its crude but its actually spot on for my purposes. The only thing that i cant do is zoom in to my points of interest as the background image is static. I wish there was a way to zoom the background image to anchor parts of the image to coordinates on the graph.

Comment: There is no code because I'm not even sure how to approach this. All I have is the plotting of my points which works and chart.BackImage = "worlMap.png". that shows the map but I can't re-position the graphic to line up with coordinates.

Comment: I sort of resolved it by adding a background image and then assigning the extents of the graph to static values. I added that to my original post.

Comment: I got this working as well but I'm seeing the same issue with the zoom..  I'd like to be able to zoom and have the image reference change as well.  Anything new on this?

Comment: No not really. If I were to revisit this I would use DotSpatial which is a GIS component that seems to work pretty well. And it's open source and free.